# I'm trying to figure out how to get my program to work in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So a class project I have to do it make this program but I want it to work in a `JFrame` so it has its own GUI. Here is what I have for the program.

```
package college.rhys.test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class trial {    


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Grade format is ppp,mpp,mmm,dmm,ddd:");         
        System.out.println("Please enter Btec Grade:");
        String Kboard = input.nextLine();

        if(Kboard.equals("ppp")){
            System.out.println("You have 120 UCAS points");             
        } else if(Kboard.equals("mpp")){
            System.out.println("You have 160 UCAS points!");
        } else if(Kboard.equals("mmm")){
            System.out.println("You have 240 UCAS points!");
        } else if(Kboard.equals("dmm")){
            System.out.println("You have 280 UCAS points!");
        } else if(Kboard.equals("ddd")){
            System.out.println("You have 360 UCAS points!");
        } }             
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you tried using a JFrame. Are you asking the SO community to do your work for you? That isn't how this site works.

Comment: plz read basic swing tutorial

Comment: *"So a class project I have to do it make this program.."*  If the task is not about GUIs I'd recommend ***not*** making it a GUI, but instead using any extra time you have to make the command line version work better or be better written or documented.

Comment: I know i havent attempted to put it in a jframe what i was asking is if anyone can recommend how to go about that

Comment: @poketis You should probably head over to [Programmers StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) if you'd like to know something about conceptual problems.

Answer (score 0):

Get your grade from a text box and then store it in a string variable

If your String equals the defined character, display a message box with the points.

*First thing, you neeed a frame and then add text box , button to it.* (you can also use a panel)

*On button click, you need to get the textbox value and compare it.*

*Based on the comparison results, display your message box.*

*[Here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jtextfield-basic-tutorial-and-examples) you can find a basic tutorial of using frame with textboxes and buttons*

Answer (score 0):

here is what i ended up with

public class Gui extends JFrame{

```
private JTextField gradeanswer;
private JButton ppp, mpp, mmm, dmm, ddd, reset;
private String sanswer;
private double answer = 00;
private JPanel contentpanel;
boolean opchosen = false;

public Gui(){
    super("grade calculator");
    gradeanswer = new JTextField(null, 20);

    ppp = new JButton("ppp");
    mpp = new JButton("mpp");
    mmm = new JButton("mmm");
    dmm = new JButton("dmm");
    ddd = new JButton("ddd");
    reset = new JButton("Reset");

    Dimension dim = new Dimension(75,75);

    ppp.setPreferredSize(dim); mpp.setPreferredSize(dim); mmm.setPreferredSize(dim); dmm.setPreferredSize(dim);
    ddd.setPreferredSize(dim);reset.setPreferredSize(dim);

    grade g = new grade();

    ppp.addActionListener(g); dmm.addActionListener(g);
    mpp.addActionListener(g); ddd.addActionListener(g);
    mmm.addActionListener(g); reset.addActionListener(g);

    contentpanel = new JPanel();
    contentpanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    contentpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    contentpanel.add(gradeanswer, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    gradeanswer.setEditable(false);

    contentpanel.add(ppp); contentpanel.add(mpp); contentpanel.add(mmm);
    contentpanel.add(dmm); contentpanel.add(ddd); contentpanel.add(reset);

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Btec To Ucas Converer");
    contentpanel.add(label1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    label1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));


    this.setContentPane(contentpanel);
}

private class grade implements ActionListener{


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Event) {
        JButton src = (JButton) Event.getSource();
        if (src.equals(ppp)){
            if(opchosen == false){
                if (sanswer== null){
                    sanswer = "You have 120 UCAS points!";
                }}}
        if (src.equals(mpp)){
            if(opchosen == false){
                if (sanswer== null){
                    sanswer = "You have 160 UCAS points!";
                }}}
        if (src.equals(mmm)){
            if(opchosen == false){
                if (sanswer== null){
                    sanswer = "You have 240 UCAS points!";
                }}} 
        if (src.equals(dmm)){
            if(opchosen == false){
                if (sanswer== null){
                    sanswer = "You have 280 UCAS points!";
                }}}         
        if (src.equals(ddd)){
            if(opchosen == false){
                if (sanswer== null){
                    sanswer = "You have 360 UCAS points!";
                }}} 
        if (src.equals(reset)){
            if(opchosen == false){
                if (sanswer!= null){
                    gradeanswer.setText("");
                }}} 


        if (opchosen == false){
        gradeanswer.setText(sanswer);
    }
        if (src.equals(reset)){
            if(opchosen == false){
                if (sanswer!= null){
                    gradeanswer.setText("");
                    sanswer = null;
                }}}     




}



}
}
```